# Initial mysqli query preventing the next from running

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a query using a global mysqli object and then passing the mysqli object to a function called getProgramInfo to be used when running a second query. If I don't run the initial query, everything works well, but if I run the initial query, the second query does not work and fails on the $mysqli->prepare(). The SQL is valid on the second query, there seems to just be an issue with the mysqli object.

```
echo getProgramInfo($mysqli); //This works if I call this function here.

$sql = "SELECT programName FROM programs WHERE programID = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) //This query always works
{
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($programNameText);

  if ($stmt->fetch()) 
  { 
    //Do stuff;
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Error";
  }

  $mysqli->close();
}

echo getProgramInfo($mysqli); //This fails if I call the function here
```

Comment: because you closed your connection above it.

Comment: `where is this function(getProgramInfo) code? i didn't see it`

Comment: *"but if I run the initial query, the second query does not work and fails on the $mysqli->prepare()."* - so what is the second query and how do we know which is the first? check for errors on them is all I can say http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Right... `function(???)`

Comment: >>> `$mysqli->close();
}

echo getProgramInfo($mysqli);` no more connection, out of scope, dead. *"Go directly to jail; do not pass go, do not collect $200."*

Comment: If I comment out the $mysqli->close(); statement, the result is the same.

Comment: well as stated; we don't know where that function is declared as. all we see are 2x `getProgramInfo($mysqli)` but no `function getProgramInfo()` anywhere. again, check for errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on your query.

Comment: You were correct on the closing the $mysql, I stared at it for so long but kept reading it as $stmt->close(). I have failed at reading comprehension of my own code.

Comment: @Columbus Another happy ending then. I posted my answer below, since my first comment was correct all along ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> *"You were correct on the closing the $mysql, I stared at it for so long but kept reading it as $stmt->close(). I have failed at reading comprehension of my own code. – Columbus"*

As stated in my first comment; you closed the connection too soon in your code.

Therefore, either remove `$mysqli->close();` since MySQL will close it automatically, or place it after your last function call.

```
echo getProgramInfo($mysqli); //This fails if I call the function here
$mysqli->close();
```